# Java. Не получается удалить папку, содержащую файл

Tags: java, методы

По замыслу этот код должен создать папку на рабочем столе, создать в ней пустой документ .txt, а затем удалить сначала файл, затем папку. Все работает. Я убираю метод, удаляющий файл - по-идее программа должна удалить папку, вместе с файлом, который в ней лежт. Но ничего не происходит. Почему?

```
public class FileCreator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*Создаем папку на рабочем столе*/
        String folderName = "My Folder";
        String folderPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";

        File myFolder = new File(folderPath + "/" + folderName);
        myFolder.mkdir();

        /*Создаем текстовый докмент в созданной выше папке*/
        String fileName = "My File.txt";
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/My Folder";

        File myFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName);

        try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* myFile.delete(); - раньше удалял файл, сейчас закомментен */
        myFolder.delete();

    }
}
```

Comment: П.с файловая система такая штука, что тут иерархия, папка в папке, файл в папке, обрезать начало, а конец куда делся? в файловой системе затерялся, а как в него доступ получить а? Поэтому используйте метод File есть, он подробно удаляет все файлы и в итоге папочку

Comment: @ДенисКотляров Спасибо большое за совет! Буду изучать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заглядываем в [документацию на `File.delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-), читаем:

> If the file is a directory then the directory must be empty.

то есть

> Если файл является на самом деле каталогом, то этот каталог должен быть пустым.

В списке бросаемых исключений [`DirectoryNotEmptyException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryNotEmptyException.html).

Удаляйте файл(ы) перед удалением каталога.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Изучаю с нуля, еще не освоился.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin: Пожалуйста! Удачи вам в изучении языка!

Comment: Эх, спасибо! :)